# Area of a skew quadrilateral

Tags: matlab, geometry

Does anyone have suggestions/algorithms on how to calculate the surface area of a skew quadrilateral? (I believe skew quadrilateral = a quadrilateral whose vertices are not planar)

Comment: This is more of a general math/geometry problem than a programming problem. I think you'll have a lot better luck over at http://math.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Unless you define the manifold the quadrilateral lives in, there are infinite answers

Answer (score 0):

If your quadrilateral is embedded in d dimensions, then you can calculate the height of the quadrilateral by projecting the vector passing through one of the parallel sides onto the line passing through the other two parallel sides and computing the projection's length between the two sides of the original direction, and then the area is the length of the projection vector multiplied by the length of the side you projected onto.

Comment: I understand, but I believe this is only true if the quadrilateral is planar; however a skew quadrilateral does not have a planar surface, (e.g. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SkewQuadrilateral.html)